# pythonanywhere is not updating mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, flask, async-await, pythonanywhere

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
    info = request.args
    if info["password"] == info["password2"] and info["name"] and info["email"] and info["password"] and info["password2"]:
        password = os.getenv("password")
        link = 'mongodb+srv://yakov:' + password + '@cluster0.irzzw.mongodb.net/myAuctionDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
        client = MongoClient(link)
        db = client.get_database('myAuctionDB')
        users = db.users
        users.insert_one({
            'name': info["name"],
            'email': info["email"],
            'password': info["password"],
            'sales': [],
            'offers': [],
            'saved': []
        })
        return jsonify({"status": "ok", "message": " welcome to {} {} ".format(info["name"], info["email"])})
    else:
        return jsonify({"status": "error", "message": "you are missing some arguments"})
```

this is my code, it works when i run it locally from my computer.
i saved it on a host called pythonanywhere, and the code works, but it does not insert the json to mongoDB, it gives me this error "500 Internal Server Error".
this is the response when i run it locally:
[image]

this is the response of the same code when i run it through pythonanywhere:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated the question, and explained better what I meant, thanks for the comment

Comment: Are you using a free account?  If so you wil be not able to connect with an external service.  See more in the [PythonAnywhere docs](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/KindsOfDatabases/).

Comment: I am using a free account, thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a free acount in pythonanywhere, does not allow to connect to mongodb atlas, so when it runs on pythonanywhere, it does not connect to the database, and does not work